# How to factorise the following linear differential equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question, problem-solving, factoring

I have been doing factorisation problems on linear differential equation and I faced a problem which I could not solve:
$(D^2-(3/x )D+3/x^2)y=e^x+3$
How to break the differential expression into linear factors?
Is there any general technique or rule of hand to write the factors at a glance?

Comment: @Jon Please write properly in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewriting it as:$$x^2y''-3xy'+3y=x^2(e^x+3)$$
This is Euler's equation:
$$(xD(xD-1)-3xD+3)y=x^2(e^x+3)$$
$$(xD(xD-1)-3(xD-1)y=x^2(e^x+3)$$
$$(xD-1)(xD-3)y=x^2(e^x+3)$$

Where the operator $D=\frac{d} {dx}$
And $$xD(xD-1)y=xDxD y-xDy$$
$$xD(xD-1)=x^2y''+xy'-xy'=x^2y''$$

Comment: I have been asked to use $D$ as $d/dx$ and I must directly factorise $D$.

Comment: @KishalaySarkar  then your write it with your notation as  $$((xD-1)(xD-3))y=x^2(e^x+3)$$ Thats correct and now $D=dy/dx$

Comment: I used your notation in my answer. Now my D is your D notation. @KishalaySarkar

Answer (score 1):

This is an Euler Cauchy Equation. For the homogeous part, try plugging in $y=x^k$. You will get to solve $k(k-1)-3k+3=0$, so $k=1$ or $k=3$. Hence two linearly independent solutions are given by $x$ and $x^3$. The equation is not an equation where you can use the characteristic equation since the coefficients in front of $D=d/dx$ are not constant but depend on $x$.

Comment: I am asked to solve by factoring.